# How to redirect double slash in URL using NGINX

Tags: nginx, redirect, nginx-config

We have an external backlink with a double slash pointing to our website, ending on 404. Now I want to redirect that backlink to the correct version.

`/en//effective-link-prospecting-with-marketing-miner-in-4-steps.html`

to this version:

`/en/blog/effective-link-prospecting-with-marketing-miner-in-4-steps.html`

In NGINX I tried this (but it's not working I think because of double slash in the URL)

`rewrite ^/en//effective-link-prospecting-with-marketing-miner-in-4-steps.html https://www.marketingminer.com/en/blog/effective-link-prospecting-with-marketing-miner-in-4-steps.html permanent;`

Comment: Do you have any tips? :)

Comment: Have you tried your rewrite statement with a single `/`? Nginx folds multiple `/`s into a single `/` before `rewrite` gets to see it.